# How to style a specific page link navbar in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I already finish my layout design. Now I want to include my design in Wordpress themes. I have a little knowledge in Wordpress because I just started learning it for about 1 week.

This is my template (not yet wordpress)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active_link"><a href="index.php">TOP PAGE</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="product.php">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="download.php">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
    <li class="contact_us_link"><a href="contact_us"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span> CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

And what I did is I created them as a page so I have this code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

And it my last page there will be an envelope icon beside the text link and also it has a different background color.

I created this CSS for this:

```
#top-links-container .nav li:last-child {
    border: 1px solid #FB7E7E;
    background: #FB7E7E;
}
```

I got the background color but the text color didn't change.
I also tried this approach but all the text link is affected.

```
#top-links-container .nav li a:last-child {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Is there a way that I can style a specific page link? How can I add the icon beside my last page link?

Comment: Do you want to apply diff. css class to specific menu item?

Comment: Yes. And I want to add a span tag on that specific menu item

Comment: That you can do from admin option , for each menu item you have option to apply  **Css Classes**, expand menu and you will have that option. If you don't get that option then from top  **Go to Screen option -> Show advance option -> Css classes** , then again check with menu. Hope now you can apply specific class to specific menu.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
#top-links-container .nav .contact_us_link a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

You may also have to style the .fa if it's being overwritten by your other css.